# Add text to bottom footer area of Woocommerce Category Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I've read through around 30 or 40 different articles today on how to achieve this and none give a really good simple answer.

Long story short, we have circa 40 categories and simply want to add a block of text with a link within it at the foot of every category page.

So looking to edit the category page template. We have our woocommerce folder setup in child theme and have other files overriding the default plugin. So we understand that it is probably the content-product.php file that is to be edited? But where and what code is applied? Tried adding in near the bottom but it gets caught up in the loop and adds it to the page for the number of products in that category as looped with product title, image etc.

Should we look at adding custom php in our child theme's functions.php file?

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to add code to footer, then you should add via widget. Check if your existing theme layout allows you that. Its under Appearance >> Widgets

Comment: That won't work as it's just the category pages we want this on. Not all pages. My use of the word footer probably wasn't the best choice of word sorry.

Comment: You can use PHP Code widget and validate if its category page or not.

Comment: Still sits too low down the template though in the footer. We need it to sit at the bottom of the main body container area.

Comment: Oh okay. Then you can override template files and then deactivate all plugins, just activate woocommerce and then activate other plugins one by one to see which one conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can approach this but for the most part you're going to need to write some PHP.

To place something at the bottom of a category page you need to check how WooCommerce displays categories. Visiting the `taxonomy-product_cat.php` WC template will reveal that categories use `archive-product.php`. The next step would be to review that template file.

You want something to be shown at the bottom of the category page, it's only going to be displayed once so it doesn't belong inside the main products loop.

If you override the `archive-product.php` template and manually insert a link, it's going to appear not just on the categories but also the shop and tag pages. That tells you that you need a conditional to limit the display of the link.

Using the hooks WooCommerce provides means you won't have to override the template at all. There are 2 hooks in the file which may be suitable:

1. `woocommerce_after_shop_loop` - executed after the loop when there are products
2. `woocommerce_after_main_content` - executed at the bottom of the page whether or not there are products.

Write a function to output your link using one of those hooks:

```
function wpse_wc_category_footer_link() {
    // woocommerce_after_main_content is a generic hook; check we're on a category page.
    if ( ! is_product_category() ) {
        return;
    } ?>

    <!-- Your markup for category pages belongs here... -->
    <a href="#">My Link</a>

    <?php    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'wpse_wc_category_footer_link', 5 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Nathan. I don't think in this instance our theme or design is using the archive-product.php or the category pages or subcategory pages. For example, if I empty that entire file and save it, the category pages remain unchanged. Only the content-product_cat.php file seems to have a bearing on the category pages. I'll keep playing about with until I can get things happening. The help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the taxonomy-product_cat.php WC template held? Cannot locate in any of the Woocommerce folders. We are using latest version 3.0.4

Comment: Your theme may override specific WooCommerce templates. If it doesn't, the default is used and they can be found by going to `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/`